# Crisp images when rendering on GPU in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I have a question about rendering on cycles with GPU. When i render on GPU the images look a bit crispy. When i render on CPU they don't.

I have a Geforce GTX 1070 videocard and got it running on Blender with the CUDA 8 beta.

CPU
[image]

GPU

[image]

Comment: A couple examples of images rendered on both would help. Ideally in close up so you can point to the effect.

Comment: I tested it on a different computer with an older Geforce video card and on that computer the renders look good.

Here's an example how they look:
With CPU https://postimg.org/image/r9xvsfiov/

And GPU: https://postimg.org/image/o4hvfypgf/

Could it be i did something wrong when setting up the videocard driver? Because the CUDA version is still Beta?

Comment: I just found the solution on this post: It appears to be AA and should be solved when setting the Sampling settings to Branched Path Tracing.

Comment: "It appears to be AA and should be solved when setting the Sampling settings to Branched Path Tracing." What is AA?

Comment: @Dontwalk  Antialiasing.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution on this post: It appears to be AA and should be solved when setting the Sampling settings to Branched Path Tracing.